# partner community home page is not showing/displaying custom aura component for partner users(with partner community login profile)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, partner-communities, visibility

I have a issue where i am putting a custom aura component onto Partner community Home page and when i login or view the community as a system admin i am able to see the component and its functioning as required. But when i use "Log into Experience as User" on a partner user to see the behaviour of the component it is just not visible.
The component is using Lightning data services to create a case record, the partner profile has Create access on case. The component is not visible even if all of this is replaced with a simple text. Component is not using a controller. One more thing to mention here is that the component is perfectly visible if it is put onto a new blank site page, and the user navigates to that page to access the component. What might be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that there are different page variations used for partner users and internal users and that is the reason, while a internal user was able to see the component as it was placed in the page variation pertaining to that user and not in partner user's page variation which was causing the issue.